# Evitar superponer elementos html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo los siguientes elementos en mi sitio web la barra azul es un navbar en una marter page, y el textbox para buscar es contenido de otra pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al hacer mas pequeña la ventana del navegador el navbar tapa el textbox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
CSS

```html
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: midnightblue !important;
    border-color: midnightblue !important;
}

.buscar1 {
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML DEL DIV BUSCAR

```html
<div class="col-mb-12 form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 buscar1">
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-control mr-sm-2 " autocomplete="off" type="search" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search" id="cod_p"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CausesValidation="false" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 btn-rounded "  id="BtnSearch" onclick="BtnSearch_Click" >
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search "></span></asp:LinkButton>
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CausesValidation="false" class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0 btn-rounded " type="submit" id="Reset" onclick="Reset_Click" >
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh "></span></asp:LinkButton>
 </div>
```

navbar en MasterPage

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header menu">
<a href="" class="navbar-brand" runat="server">MySite</a>
</div>
<div class="dropdown opciones">
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" role="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Opciones
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
<a class="dropdown-item submenu" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CambiarC">Cambiar contraseña</a>
<a class="dropdown-item submenu" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Logout">Cerrar sesion</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

agrégale propiedades Position y display.

Yo le pondría.

```
position:relative;
display:block;
```

Comment: al navbar o al div bucar1?

Comment: a ambos. Recuerda que cada clase o id contiene propiedades CSS. lo mejor es que coloques la mayor cantidad de propiedades a cada clase, de esta forma no tendras los valores predeterminados y te pasa lo que te esta pasando

Comment: Deberías poner ese comentario dentro de la respuesta, que está un poco pobre (de hecho se ha marcado como de baja calidad automáticamente por eso)

Comment: @JonathanDiaz no creo conveniente que toque ambos. La razón es que los navbar de los extremos superior e inferior de la pantalla suelen tener el atributo **fixed** para ser mantenidos visibles sin desplazarse con el resto de la página.

Comment: De otro lado, como el div que contiene al buscador si va a poder desplazarse hacia arriba se debe asignar algún atributo para asegurar su posición. De momento no se como hacerlo de modo elegante, por esa razón entré a mirar esta pregunta.

Comment: @Huntzberger de momento te sugiero usar el selector **next-sibling** **( + )** para asignar un atributo *margin-top* suficiente al elemento siguiente a tu navbar de modo que su contenido se vea debajo del mismo. Así: Asigna la clase *navontop* al div superior y escribe el estilo `.navontop + div { margin-top: 24px; }` o el tamaño que desees. Tal vez no es lo mejor pero funciona.